# Isn't it useless to define space and time complexity in terms of properties of a tree when the reason we are searching is to explore the tree?

Tags: algorithm, search, tree, big-o

In my intro artificial intelligence course, we looked at several different search algorithms and their properties. When analyzing their space and time complexities, we would draw up a big-O complexity which was **in terms of properties of the tree itself** (for example, the branching factor b or the depth of the shallowest solution d).

My problem is that defining time and space complexity in this way seems completely useless, given that the whole point we are searching for a solution in the first place is because we don't know the nature of the tree/solution (the path to it, how shallow it is, etc.). So, to my current understanding, this form of time/space complexity analysis does not give someone who must select an algorithm for their search problem a meaningful way to discern which one is better (in terms of time/space complexity).

Comment: The complexity determines how much of the tree it is practical to explore.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Exactly, so why are we defining the practicality of exploring the tree in terms of properties of tree itself, which would require its prior exploration? That's my question if it wasn't clear.

Comment: No, we explore the tree, like the game tree of chess, to find a solution, like the best possible move.  The general properties of the tree are known beforehand, at least statistically.

Comment: @MattTimmermans for example, for DFS, we are told that the time complexity is O(b^m) where b is the branching factor and m is the maximum is the max depth. But wouldn't we have to explore the tree to know b and m? Or are you saying we can have a decent statistical estimation without exploring.

Comment: Yes, for that example, you would typically have an expectation about average branching factor, and m would be a value that you *choose* depending on the complexity of the search algorithm.  i.e., "how much of the tree it is practical to explore"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing @Matt Timmermans' comment above as it answers my question:

"...you would typically have an expectation about average branching factor, and m would be a value that you choose depending on the complexity of the search algorithm. i.e., "how much of the tree it is practical to explore"."

From what I understand (also drawing from @AbcAeffchen's answer), we estimate the value of variables like b and m to try and concoct an estimate specific to our tree so we don't have to fall back on worst-case analysis which many times does not reflect reality. This provides us with a more fine-grained **estimate**. We would not, however, care about the actual values of b and m.

Answer (score 0):

Time and space complexity analysis is very often a very tricky beast.

Over the last several decades the worst case analysis was a useful tool to reason about running times and space requirements. However, as it turns out, worst case analysis does surprisingly often contradict what we observe in reality. This drives the search for better complexity analysis types. The currently most common are average case and fine grained complexity.

In average case we don't look for the worst case but try to describe what an average case looks like, resulting in a lot of statistical analysis and stochastics to define how such instances look like and what properties they have.

In fine grained complexity we try to separate the universe of all input instances into multiple categories with different properties and analyze the complexity for them separately. A softer version of this is to introduce additional parameters of your instances to be able to show differences between algorithms.

So even though you do not know exactly what the parameters are in your specific instances, you can maybe find some bounds.

As an example: Suppose you have several algorithms to find an item in an unsorted pile of data and all have the same worst case time and space complexity. But when you look closer, you find out that some have a very good average complexity in terms of the input size. Maybe some have a constant time complexity if the position of the searched item has some properties. Such information is very useful since in practice problems often come with a lot of additional structure.

However, in the end one always has to test algorithms for the give use-case. E.g. If you want to sort 5 TB of data that is stored on hard drives you will notice that quick sort is a very bad choice and you should use some external memory library that implements some kind of multi-way merge sort. If you want to sort tiny lists of up to 10 elements it is probably faster to use bubblesort instead of merge sort oder quick sort.